# How do I autoplay this Flash automation for a website?

Tags: javascript, flash, embed

I'm grabbing the source code from localtimes.info/getwidget/20100

I'm confused as to why this site's clock autoplays but [when I embed mine, it displays a "Play Button" on my site like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMX5U.png)

[image]

This is the code it has provided me.

```
<div style="margin: 15px 0px 0px; display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<div style="display: inline-block; padding: 2px 4px; margin: 0px 0px 5px; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); text-align: center; background-color: transparent;">
<a href="http://localtimes.info/difference" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 13px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">World Clock</a></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localtimes.info/world_clock2.php?&cp1_Hex=ffffff&cp2_Hex=4b4b4b&cp3_Hex=006766&fwdt=88&ham=0&hbg=1&hfg=0&sid=0&mon=0&wek=0&wkf=0&sep=0&widget_number=20100&lcid=UKXX0085,USKY0854,USIN0102,USWI0474,USWA0331"></script></div>
```

[I know I can activate Flash manually here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVyoD.png) But how can I make it a global default for my visitors like the source websites?

Answer (score 0):

> *"I'm confused as to why this site's clock autoplays but when I embed mine, it displays a "Play Button" on my site like this."*

Because of two things: **Display size** and the Flash app is coming from **external server**.

Possible Solutions (choose A or B):

**(A)** - Run the Flash app (swf file) from your own server (same location as your html file).

**(B)** - Increase the display size to minimum 800 x 600.